# How to always start powershell.exe with the NoProfile option set as default?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, command-line-interface

I need that `powershell.exe` always executes with the `-noprofile` option set when I first open it.

How can this be achieved? I searched a lot, and didn't find any way to do this.

**work around**: I changed Windows Terminal and VSCode's json settings to always start powershell.exe with the -noprofile option. In WindowsTerminal:

```json
"commandline": "%SystemRoot%\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -noprofile"
```

**Obs**: I want to do this because starting PowerShell in any environment (VSCode, Windows Terminal, etc) always takes more than 2 seconds. When I run the executable with the -NoProfile option, it instantaneous. Some have suggested to empty the `profile.ps1` file, but it doesn't even exists.

Comment: It redirected me to a WindowsPowerShell directory in my Documents. There's one single file in there: `profile.ps1`. I opened with notepad and there's some conda configuration at the startup.

Comment: Try `$Profile | Select *` which will show all the locations where profile scripts may exist

Comment: delete each occurrence of the profile if you don't care about those configs. It's most likely getting hung up on trying to set some options where as -noprofile is just bypassing that hang

Comment: It showed me 4 files. But only one of these exist, the one with the conda configs. All others, if I try to open them with notepad, I will be creating a new file

Comment: yeah it does that by default, just delete the one under your documents

Comment: Ok, deleted the occurrences. It is starting faster now